# DOMPDF whole table was broke to a new page when my table filled up

Tags: php, dompdf

I'm using version Dompdf 0.8.5

This is my code and my PDF render:

```
<div>header</div>
<div>title</div>
<div>somethingelse</div>

<div class="detail" style="width:100%">
    <table id="tbDetail" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 11.5px">
        <thead>
            <tr class="detail-header">
                <td class="br-1 bb-1 bt-1 text-center" style="width:3%">NBR</td>
                <td class="br-1 bb-1 bt-1 text-center" style="width:35%">Product</td>
                <td class="br-1 bb-1 bt-1 text-center" style="width:13%">Unit</td>
                <td class="br-1 bb-1 bt-1 text-center" style="width:10%">Quantity</td>
                <td class="br-1 bb-1 bt-1 text-center" style="width:17%">Price</td>
                <td class="br-1 bb-1 bt-1 text-center" style="width:19%">Total</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each
                    select="(//node())[37 >= position()]">
                <tr class="detail-data text-left">
                    <td>&#160;</td>
                    <td>&#160;</td>
                    <td>&#160;</td>
                    <td>&#160;</td>
                    <td>&#160;</td>
                    <td>&#160;</td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: is your HTML/xml output correct?
please double check that. Problem seems there

Comment: my html/xml just like that : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2190?fbclid=IwAR2dDiG3YWQiLwffmAQ_fy8uSNoeCpSGbBfj6ticO0dxv_ZqzBJ6Bk2dKtA#issuecomment-654278486

Comment: I have commented you your thread there. please check and hope it helps

Comment: It's a bug. this code i'm using v 8.0.5 but when i use v 8.0.1 i resolve my issue